# Implementing WordNetdotNet in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, wordnet

I'm currently having issues with integrating the WordNet library from WordNetdotNet.  I get a compiling error from Unity in the "Settings.Designer.cs" file:

*error CS0234: The type or namespace name "ApplicationSettingsBase" does not exist in the namespace `System.Configuration'. Are you missing an assembly reference?*

Below is the code for "Settings.Designer.cs"

```
namespace Properties {

[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "8.0.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase  {

    public static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any guidance would be appreciated!

WordNetdotNet git: https://github.com/ebswift/wordnetdotnet

*Settings.Designer.cs is located in the "Library > cs > Properties" folder.

Comment: Are you able to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example in code that you can share? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @CharlieJoynt I edited the post to include the code

Comment: Let's hope that someone who can answer comes along soon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Xamarin Studio?

You are not referencing the assembly `System.Configuration`.

Just right-click on the `References` folder and `Edit References` where you can find then add this assembly.

[image]

Comment: The tag says Unity

Comment: Sure, but Unity uses an IDE for C#. Depending on the OS it is typically Xamarin on Mac or VS/Sharp Develop on Windows. The OP clearly has a reference to an assembly missing so he can google how to add based on his IDE.

Comment: @EatatJoes Hi thank you for the quick response.  I am using MonoDevelop in Unity and did exactly what you suggested; however, the same error is still present when I add the System.Configuration package to the Assembly References.  I saved the project and restarted Unity - and noticed that the System.Configuration package was missing (even though I added it in before and it clearly showed)... I tried adding the package in Visual Studio and it disappears after I save it and exit out of the program as well. Any idea on what could be the issue?